# Find all values in json array in with Retrofit

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mobile, retrofit2

I need to find and separate the values in json with Retrofit. With this code I get the whole body:

```
 val retrofitCliente = NetworkUtils.getRetrofitInstance("https://aprimorandoapi.000webhostapp.com/")
    val endpointiface = retrofitCliente.create(Endpoint::class.java)
    val call: Call<JsonObject?>? = endpointiface.getNoticias()
    var data = ArrayList<String>()

    endpointiface.getNoticias()?.enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<JsonObject?> {

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<JsonObject?>, response: Response<JsonObject?>) {

            val corpo = response.body()

            val indice1 = data.indexOf("noticias")
            Log.d("Corpo json",+corpo.toString())


        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<JsonObject?>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d("falhoujson","falhajson")
        }
```

But, I want to insert each item in ArrayList as my method returns. My JSON is:

```
{
"noticias":[ {
                "texto": "Vagas remanescentes para cursos técnicos no CEFORES. Para se inscrever, basta clicar no link abaixo",
                "url_imagem": "teste"
            },
             {
                "texto": "PROACE divulga a abertura do 2º Processo Seletivo Simplificado de Monitoria Inclusiva na modalidade de Apoio Pedagógico Remoto para o calendário acadêmico 2022/01",
                "url_imagem": "teste"
            },
             {
                "texto": "Projeto fomenta expressão e diálogo de cultura do campo",
                "url_imagem": "teste"
            },
            {
                "texto": "Ministério das Relações Exteriores endossa candidatura do Projeto Geopark Uberaba - Terra de Gigantes",
                "url_imagem": "teste"
            }
        ]
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your build.gradle (Module) and SyncNow:

```
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9'
```

Make a data class for your data item

```
data class Noticia(
@SerializedName("texto")
val text: String,
@SerializedName("url_imagem")
val image: String)
```

make yourself a favor in future and use the plugin 'Kotlin data Class from JSON' -
you will find it in the marketplace

define an interface (separate file)
i'm unsure with the @GET("noticias.json") i assume only the noticias.json

```
interface NoticiaApiService {

@GET("noticias.json")
fun getNoticias(): Call<List<Noticia>>
}
```

make a the call (this is quite unclean but it should work)

```
fun getNoticias(){
val retrofit: Retrofit =
    Retrofit
        .Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .baseUrl("https://aprimorandoapi.000webhostapp.com/")
        .build()
val restInterface = retrofit.create(NoticiaApiService::class.java)
val noticiasCall = restInterface.getNoticias()
noticiasCall.enqueue(
    object : Callback<List<Noticia>> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Noticia>>, response: Response<List<Restaurant>>) {
            response.body()?.let {
                //i assume you will save the values in your viewModel?
                //you can also same it somewhere else
                noticasLiveData.value = it
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Noticia>>, t: Throwable) {
            t.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
)
}
```

happy coding

Comment: What about noticasLiveData variable? It updates dinamically?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#work_livedata